# Taking part of CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a very large CSV file which I should analyze. 
It's too big so I can't even open it in Excel or Stata. 
So I want to take first few rows of it and explore the data, and then select necessary columns.

What I need it a software which take specific rows or columns of a csv file and output it as a separate file.
(e.g. I want to take Row 1~2500 or Column A,B,C and E)
Which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell.

```
PS > get-content \Large.csv -totalcount 2500 > Output.txt
```

[image]

You put \Large.csv as the Path to your Csv.

You put Output.txt as where you want the output to go say C:/Usere/Documents/Output.txt

[image]

Comment: You've only answer half the question. "I want to take ... Column A,B,C and E"

Comment: @DavidPostill He said he wanted to either Take row 1-2500 or Columns like A,B,C and E? So I answered for pulling from row 2500 to a text file.

Comment: Yes. I understand. But his question was in two parts.

Comment: I see. He could take the .txt off and put it to csv then select the columns he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the free Microsoft Add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010)
or rather the open source [R statistical software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) .

The first is quite intuitive for Loading and transforming your data for several source types. However the ouptut will be as a table in Excel or in the data model (Power Pivot feature). With VBA there is however a way to produce a CSV, s. [Blogpost](http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/) from Kasper de Jonge.

R is probably also suitable to subset your datas or later produce an output CSV file. First hints [here](http://rprogramming.net/write-csv-in-r/) or on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391880/how-to-get-a-csv-file-into-r).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at [TextQ](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/textq/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can import a big CSV file and lets you view and query it.

You can query via a UI Query Builder or SQL, which supports limit and offset parameters. Then you can export any query to a CSV file, which can be imported in MS Excel or others.

Here is a [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ozIZPuQF8&t=11s) and [more detailed tutorial](https://medium.com/@geo.systems.developer/textq-analysing-and-filtering-huge-csv-files-4a45561613bb).

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/textq/id1571423170) or Microsoft Store (coming soon).